# Does GCP VPC SC service supports Cloud Source Repository or not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-vpc, cicd, google-cloud-source-repos

There is a scenario to have cloud source repository inside VPC SC perimeter to build CI/CD pipelines inside the perimeter to build & deploy the solutions.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products

But the Google Doc doesn't have clear information about this . Could anyone advise if you have already worked / tried this scenario.

Comment: In the supported products page you linked, there is no mention of cloud source repositories as supported by VPC SC. 

The only repos mentioned are the ones for Artifact Registry, Cloud Composer and Container Registry which are available regardless of service perimeters. Can you share where you found the scenario you mention?

Comment: Its not like I have found that scenario , that is the scenario our project demands . So just wanted to make sure whether VPC SC supports cloud source repositories or not before planning.

Comment: At the moment, VPC SC doesn't support source repositories, I would recommend you to create a feature request on their issue tracker so that they implement this functionality in the future https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers